# How to receive files from the same FTP location from more than one BizTalk receive location?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

In normal scenario no one would face this problem. But in my case I have three different users for the same FTP location, and each user has access to different set of files.

My objective is to configure receive ports/locations such that I am able to get all the files for all the users. For this I thought of creating 3 FTP receive locations for the same URI with different Username/pwd combination. But as expected it threw error "Address should be unique for receive location"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have different file mask for each receive location.  That will make the URI's unique.

For example if all the files have a pattern off PCK00001.xml, PCK0002.xml etc.  you can have one port looking for P*.xml, a second PC*.xml and the third as PCK*.xml.  That would be enough to make BizTalk think the URI's are unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But That is what I did. But i dont think  it is foolproof, because there is no guarantee that for each different user there will be some unique characters in the filenames, to use it as file mask. There will always be some file left out.

Comment: So there is no pattern to the files at all?  Not even the file extension?  You can do the same trick with that.

Comment: unfortunately there is no foolproof pattern which will catch all the required files. :( I need files with all the extension of all the users.